# Pandas DataFrame expand existing dataset to finer timestamp

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, timestamp

I am trying to make this piece of code faster, it is failing on conversion of ~120K rows to ~1.7m.

Essentially, I am trying to convert each date stamped entry into 14, representing each DOW from PayPeriodEndingDate to T-14

Does anyone have a better suggestion other than iteruples to do this loop?

Thanks!!

```
df_Final = pd.DataFrame()

for row in merge4.itertuples():

    listX = []
    listX.append(row)

    df = pd.DataFrame(listX*14)
    df = df.reset_index().drop('Index',axis=1)

    df['Hours'] = df['Hours']/14
    df['AmountPaid'] = df['AmountPaid']/14
    df['PayPeriodEnding'] = np.arange(df.loc[:,'PayPeriodEnding'][0] - np.timedelta64(14,'D'), df.loc[:,'PayPeriodEnding'][0], dtype='datetime64[D]')

    frames = [df_Final,df]

    df_Final = pd.concat(frames,axis=0)

 df_Final
```

Comment: I can't make your code run faster if I don't know what it does, and your explanation does not help. Please provide some sample data to help us understand what's going on here.

Comment: Also, never use a for loop when working with pandas.

Comment: data is simply a DF with 3x columns , 1. Hours, 2. AmountPaid, 3. PayPeriodEnding integer values for 1 and 2 and datetime64 for 3.

What can I use instead of a for loop?

Comment: Again, describing your data in english does not help. I want to see 5-10 rows of your data along with sample output. It's literally the _best and easiest_ way for you to get a good answer out of me.